# Loop List of List string with a condition the same order on the extraction C#

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, foreach

I have a list of list string:

```
  List<List<string>> donnees = new List<List<string>>();
```

My objective is to extract a list of XElement, and the XElement verify a condition:
I want each line to contain the values of each list and all must be of the same order

For exemple with this List donnees

```
   donnees : { { "a","b","c","d"}, {"1", "2", "3", "4"}, { "first", "second", "third", "fourth"} }
```

I want to get list values like this:

```
<value> "a", "1", "first" </value>
<value> "b", "2", "second" </value>
<value> "b", "3", "third" </value>
<value> "d", "4", "fourth" </value>
```

( In fact: get all the values for each list of the same order )

Of course I have a very large list,

I test with this

```
foreach (List<string> list in donnees)
{
foreach (string s in list)
{
  //Here to get the XElement with the values 
  //It is OK
}
}
```

But it is not the purpose,
So how can I fix it ? Thanks ,

Comment: are we suppose to be under the assumption that each list has the same elements.  If so just use a for loop, based on the number of elements in the first internal list, and then use the index to obtain the value in each list

Comment: /\ and the same number of elements?

Comment: And also, what is the outcome you are getting? Using your same example data, can you show us what your result is?

Comment: Thanks for you all, @Anu Viswan find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially attempting to read a List of List Column-wise and then combine the result. You could do so using a nested loop.

Following method should help you to create the desired collection of `XElement`

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> GetList(List<List<string>> source)
{
    var maxIndex= source.Max(x=>x.Count());
    var index = 0;

    while(index<maxIndex)
    {
        var lineList = new List<string>();
        foreach(var list in source.Select(x=>x))
        {
            if(list.Count > index)
                lineList.Add($"\"{list[index]}\"");
        }
        index++;
        yield return new XElement("value", string.Join(",",lineList));
    }
}
```

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tQQKU6)

Answer (score -1):

Just iterate by **index**:

```
var result = new List<(string, string, string)>();
for(int i = 0; i < donnees[0].Count; i++)
{
    result.Add((donnes[0][i], donnees[1][i], donnees[2][i]));
}
```

Comment: doesn't this assume there are only three elements per list?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Sure. I´m not sure if this is a good or a bad thing, though.

Answer (score -1):

LINQ:

```
donnees.Select(d =>
{
   string[] items = d.Select(i => "\" + i + "\")).ToArray();
   return $"<value>{string.Join(", ", items)}</value>");
}
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, you should improve the quality of your answer by explaining what this code does and how it is meant to fix the original problem -- this helps other users reading your answer understand what is going on.